# objective-c iphone online database

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml, parsing, ios4

Hey, I am trying to develop an iphone application where users upload to an online database and retrieve information from the database.

My question is what would the best way to parse data from an xml file into a UITableView and update the information every 6 seconds.

the database is going to be very active, as in a record inserted into the database may only last for a few minutes as it is essentially displaying a list of online users. once a user goes offline ( i will be using the viewDidUnload method to delete a user from the database )

im thinking the best way to do this, is to init a object with viewDidLoad which will hold the users information, then once the view has loaded, the user inputs data, presses a button then the information is stored in an object which is uploaded to a .php script running on my server. this information is then stored in my database.

to retrieve the information, im going to use xml. I have developed this quick script

```
<?php
include('includes/connect.php');
header("Content-type: text/xml");
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>';
echo '<online_users>';

$sql2="SELECT * FROM `numbers` WHERE `deleted` = '0'";
$result2=mysql_query($sql2);
if (!$result2) die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    echo '<user>';
        echo '<name>'.$row2["name"].'</name>';
        echo '<hereFor>'.$row2["cat_name"].'</hereFor>';
        echo '<gender>'.$row2["gender"].'</gender>';
    echo '</user>';
}
    echo '</online_users>';

?>
```

so how would i go about parsing the data into a UITableView and update the table view every 6 seconds.

if their is a better way of doing this, I am open to suggestions.

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't said if you've tried writing any iPhone code yet or where you're at with it.

A general first strategy to attack this would be to work on the following parts of the puzzle:

1) Some code to use a library such as [ASIHTTP](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) (or even just NSURLConnection out of the box) to perform the fetch of the XML data

2) Some code to parse the XML which comes back -- have a look at using NSXMLParser

3) Work on your UI - you need to make a table view (see UITableView) that can show the data appropriately

The above misses out lots of things, but it's a start.